# Question about Schengen tourism visa and third party nationals

Tags: germany, europe, schengen-visas, covid-19, greece

I plan to travel on a Schengen short term tourism visa next month. I plan to go to Greece as it is open to US travelers (both nationals and permanent residents).

My current itinerary is via Frankfurt. In the past whenever I traveled to Schengen area -- I got immigration stamp at the first port of entry in the Schengen area. However currently Germany is not allowing any third party nationals outside of Schengen area for immigration.

If in case Germany still not allowing any third country nationals next month - then how will it work with regards to immigration?

I found some information on Germany's federal foreign website - https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/coronavirus/2317268#content_5

And looks like travelers with end destination in Schengen area will get immigration stamp in Germany. However, there's entry ban in the Germany for anyone outside EU and select few countries (unfortunately US is not part of it). So I'm really confused.

Would you recommend to book direct flight to Athens from the US to avoid any hassles?

Comment: A direct flight without the unpredictable complications of transit seems by far the better option, IMHO

Comment: Read: [BMI - Migration - Travel restrictions / border control](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/travel-restrictions-border-control/travel-restriction-border-control-list.html)  **When is transit through Germany permitted?** *Transit through Germany to travel to another EU member state or another Schengen member state*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.